# Why are silicon analogs of alkenes or alkynes so difficult to make?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, covalent-compounds

We know that there are silicon analogs of alkanes, but according to Wikipedia, silicon analogs of alkenes or alkynes are virtually unknown. How come?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The typical Si–Si single bond length in a silane is around 2.33 Å.  This is much longer than a typical C–C single bond (~1.53 Å) and helps explain why silicon-silicon single bonds are so much weaker than carbon-carbon single bonds (bond dissociation energy: ~53 kcal/mol for silicon-silicon *vs.* ~83 kcal/mol for carbon-carbon single bonds).  When we try to form a silicon-silicon double or triple bond, the large separation between the two silicon atoms results in even **less effective p-orbital overlap and therefore even weaker π-bonds**.  The result is that while [disilenes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27839/why-does-si2h4-readily-polymerize-at-rtp-but-ethene-does-not-requires-catalyst/27854#27854) and [disilynes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16538/why-is-disilyne-bent/16543#16543) are known (see the linked SE Chem posts), they are **extremely** reactive.  Only when bulky substituents are placed around the double or triple bonds (to provide some "steric protection" against further reaction) can the molecules be isolated and characterized.

Answer (score 11):

Just to add to ron's answer with some information on the properties of the silicon analogues.

1. Silicon "alkynes"

These exotic compounds were first reported on in 2004 in [this paper.](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/305/5691/1755) Typically show bond order somewhat less than 3; the HOMO has some non-bonding/lone pair character which is also manifest in a small deviation from linearity. The silicon-silicon "triple" bond is pretty reactive and most examples have very bulky alkyl substituents to create a steric barrier to reaction.

2. Silenes

These have been known since 1981; the first example being [tetramesitylsilene](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/214/4527/1343.abstract). Similar to the "alkynes", (trans) deviation from planarity and bond order less than 2 due to HOMO lone pair character observed. Decrease in Si-Si bond length observed but it is smaller than that typically seen for C-C bonds.