# Ring compounds of non-carbon atoms

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Are there compounds that are rings of non-carbon atoms, say a ring of six oxygen atoms, or 5-6 nitrogen atoms with attached hydrogens?
Or are these too unstable to exist for long (if at all), like long oxygen chains ($\ce{HO_{n}H}$)?

Comment: [This one’s pretty close](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/US20090133787A1/US20090133787A1-20090528-C00002.png) ;)

Comment: Are you looking for a single element around the ring? Otherwise borazine would count: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borazine

Comment: Sulphur forms many cyclic allotropes, and phosphorous has some as well.

Comment: There are many common rings with more than one element in them and no carbons. Single element rings seem harder.

Comment: Good answers so far. Anyone know anything about rings of Oxygen? It wouldn't be aromatic since there wouldn't be any bonds left over. Right?

Comment: You can have oxygen atoms in aromatic rings (furan, pyrilium ion), but making such a ring out of oxygen alone would force it to have too much concentrated positive charge.

Comment: Non-carbon cyclic structures can also be found in 3D; [boranes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boranes) yield several examples of cages, as well as some [few-atom metal clusters](http://www.rsc.org/chemistryworld/News/2006/May/16050602.asp).

Comment: see this:-http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42612/stability-of-isomers-of-n4o

Comment: It seems there is theoretically an O4 square ring https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetraoxygen, but it doesn't actually exist. But there is an O8 square block if you squeeze hard enough: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_oxygen#Red_oxygen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Pentazole](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12744347) exists - an $\ce{N5H}$ ring. It is stabilised by aromaticity, with 6 $\pi$-electrons in a cyclic, planar system.

[image]

Sulphur forms *many* allotropes which are rings but these do not contain hydrogen. $\ce{S8}$ and $\ce{S7}$ are the most common.

Phosphorus also forms cyclic allotropes such as white phosphorous, $\ce{P4}$.

[image]

DavePhD also mentioned in his answer that a silicon analogue of benzene has been synthesised recently but it is not $\ce{Si6H6}$ because it has other groups attached to some of the silicon atoms.

Comment: Pentazole does not quite exist. I mean, well, it kinda does, but that's not quite the same kind of "exists" as benzene or anything...

Comment: I doubt that counting lone pairs in pentazole is good idea here. Also many substituted ones are more stable.

Comment: Not 10 $\pi$ electrons.  Only six, isoelectronic with pyrrhole.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Oh yes sorry my mistake.

Comment: You can also have $S_8$: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Molecular_Sulfur_%28S8%29_V.1.svg/2000px-Molecular_Sulfur_%28S8%29_V.1.svg.png

Answer (score 3):

See [Silicon goes aromatic](http://www.rsc.org/chemistryworld/News/2010/January/29011001.asp) :

> Chemists in the UK have constructed a structural analogue of benzene made from silicon atoms. The molecule is not flat like benzene, but it reveals a new type of aromatic stabilisation.

Comment: See [Why isn't the Silicon analogue of Benzene flat?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32660/why-isnt-the-silicon-analogue-of-benzene-flat) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget the trihydrogen cation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trihydrogen_cation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triatomic_hydrogen).  This has been found in the interstellar medium and in hydrogen-rich planetary atmospheres, and is believed to be responsible for the formation of early-generation stars.

Comment: The trihydrogen cation is an interesting case. Though you can draw a triangular ring between the nuclei, as far as I understand the highest electron density is actually at the centre of the resulting triangle, so you could think of it more like three atoms joined by a Y-shaped bond than a ring.